# Is there any event driven technique in oracle to use with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, events, web

Is there any event driven technique in oracle to use with asp.net which should be capable of showing data in real time?

My requirement is simple but may be tricky..

I have an Oracle database containing weather data of different places which are changing time to time. I need to develop a web application to view those data from oracle in real time, that means as soon as a record is updated in database, the new value should be visible on the web page immediately.

For this, the select statement should be executed when a record is updated.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using oracle database change notification feature. You have to use ODP.Net for this. Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/OracleDependencyClass.htm) on how to use this. This will allow a noiificationm from Oracle to your ASP.Net application.
An example is also proved [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/featChange.htm#CJAGGGHA).

The other part is to have a push notification setup between the browser and server. This is possible using [web sockets](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097383) if you can use ASP.Net 4.5. However only IE 10 will support web sockets but firefox and chrome already does. There are alternate implementations as well such as [superwebsockets](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/). I haven't used this but [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) library is worth checking out.

Answer (score -1):

No, the only way is to poll database at certain interval.

Comment: @pratik the method you are talking about has lot of limitations like resource consumptions,maintenance,scalability etc. and can work for some intranet environment where you have full control on your db and app server.

Comment: have you ever used this on any of your live project ?

Comment: Scott Hanselman has blogged about SignalR being a very scalable solution compared to polling http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx I haven't used it but I have no reason to believe otherwise. What is the basis of your claims ? Also in most environment you can control your DB and app server, intranet or otherwise.

Comment: @Zia: Sorry, no. Nobody is obligated to comment on their downvotes.